# Factory Pattern when the output type is different in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I am fairly new to java and below are my mapper interface definitions:

```
public interface CourseMapper {
    Course map(JsonObject courseJson);
    List<Course> map(JsonArray coursesJson);
}

public interface LocationMapper {
    Location map(JsonObject locationJson);
    List<Location> map(JsonArray locationsJson);
}
```

and below are the two classes:

```
public interface Location {
    Long id();
    String name();
    Location mutate(Long id);
}

public interface Course {
    Long id();
    String name();
    Course mutate(Long id);
}
```

What I need is based on a key(String), I need to invoke the respective `map()` function of respective `Mapper`. Example if the `key=="location"`, I need to invoke `LocationMapper` and if the `key=="course"`, I need to invoke `CourseMapper` (for gson Mapper)...... and so on.

I tried using Factory Pattern for the same, but it seems that the same doesn't work when the Output is of different type. Would anyone know how to achieve the same without overtly complicating with if-else ladder.

Comment: "and below are the two classes" - these are interfaces, not classes.

Comment: so your `CourseMapper` and `LocationMapper`  instances going to be  stateless classes? I think, final strategy depends on that factor too since you didn't specified if you wish to invoke method on same instances or different instances for different calls.Factory makes sense when you need new instances for each call and you can store these instances in maps as specified in accepted answer if new instance creation is not needed for each call.

Comment: I need to have new instances every call, so I am modifying the accepted response to fit into Factory pattern, basically generics is what I was looking for.

Comment: Which "factory" pattern? There is simple factory, Factory method, Abstract factory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple approach is to have a `Map<String, Object>` to store your mappers in:

```
private Map<String, Object> mappers;

public <T> T getMapper(String key, Class<T> mapperType) {
    Object mapper = mappers.get(key);
    // code for when mapper == null
    if (mapperType.isAssignableFrom(mapper)) {
        return (T) mapper;
    } else {
         // code for when mapper is of wrong type
    }
}
```

As you'll notice however, this gives up static type checks, so any type mismatch will only be found at run time.

---

A more complicated approach can save (sort of) the static type checks. It basically ties the result type with the string key:

```
private static class MapperKey<T> {
    private final String key;

    public MapperKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}

private Map<String, Object> mappers;

public static final MapperKey<CourseMapper> COURSE_KEY = new MapperKey<CourseMapper>("course");

public <T> void addMapper(MapperKey<T> mapperKey, T mapper) {
    mappers.put(mapperKey.key, mapper);
}

public <T> T getMapper(MapperKey<T> mapperKey) {
    Object mapper = mappers.get(mapperKey.key);
    // code for when mapper == null
    return (T) mapper;
}
```

This approach however depends on users using the predefined constants for `MapperKey`s, or creating the correct keys (correct type parameter for the respective key).

---

And finally, if you can replace your `CourseMapper` and `LocationMapper` interfaces with this:

```
public interface Mapper<T> {
    T map(JsonObject courseJson);
    List<T> map(JsonArray coursesJson);
}
```

And if you only need one mapper per output type, you can use the output type as a key:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Mapper<?>> mappers;

public <T> void addMapper(Class<T> outputType, Mapper<T> mapper) {
    mappers.put(outputType, mapper);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getMapper(Class<T> outputType) {
    return (T) mappers.get(outputType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response- the second solution makes perfect sense!

Comment: With third option i.e. with `Mapper<T>` implementation, I guess he can solve his original challenge , **I tried using Factory Pattern for the same, but it seems that the same doesn't work when the Output is of different type**.